# how can I have two scripted operations each have their own gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, scripts

I have two scripted operations that take hours and both print to the console.  I would like to avoid having their output interleaved because that looks a bit of a mess.

How would I write a script that uses two consoles so that the output is not interleaved?

Presently each of the two operations is a script, so for example `script1.sh` and `script2.sh`.  Each scripts runs a Java program.

Presently I manually open two gnome-terminals and run the scripts separately.  Each uses the `&` to background the operation.  Ideally, there would be one script that opens two terminals.  Note that "one script" could actually be a parent script that invokes any number of, but probably 2, child scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is somewhat easy, follow the example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "

    ##############################################
    #                                               
    # to do somethings in two different terminals
    #                                                
    ##############################################
"

gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"\
gedit; \
libreoffice; \
\ # You can put your script there, before the slash.
\
exec bash\""

gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"firefox; cheese; exec bash\"" # Or just make it all in one line

exit 0
```